# Query Execution time PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, runtime

I'm using PostgreSQL jdbc version: 9.4 
I only do SELECT queries on the table.
I don't need to update, insert, or delete anything.

But the execution time is really long.. even with indexing.
Some SELECT queries are taking minute(s).
How can I improve my running time ?

This is an example of a long query:

```
Select *
FROM facts f0, facts f1
WHERE f0.Predicate='director' AND f1.Subject=f0.Subject AND f1.Predicate='writer'
```

and this is the result of: EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
[explain analyze screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juRXA.png)

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Would you please include relevant indexes? It appears your sorts are happening in temp-tables rather than using the indexed columns. We should check those. Also; please include the create table syntax for these tables or at least the output of DESCRIBE.

Comment: You need `facts.Subject` and `facts.Predicate` indexes.

Comment: Please read https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and then update the question with appropriate info. Good that you included `explain` output, though a screenshot is painful - it's much better to include the text, or paste to explain.depesz.com. More `work_mem` might help here.

Comment: @Tometzky Yes I have those indexes

Comment: @KeatsKelleher this is my table : 

CREATE TABLE facts
(
  subject character varying,
  predicate character varying,
  object character varying,
  witnesscount character varying,
  factid serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT facts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (factid)
)

Comment: I also vacuum my database all the time. So that can't be due to some dead rows

Comment: Looks like a very low work_mem. A default is 4MB, which is very conservative. I'd change that to, say, 64MB. This computer seems to have very slow disk - Amazon EBS-only instance?

Comment: @Tometzky I changed that using: alter database postgres set work_mem='500MB'; .. But the queries didn't get any faster

Comment: @HibaArnaout Wrong place - to be sure change this in postgresql.conf and restart Postgres.

Comment: @Tometzky Ok I did that too.. but apparently same speed